# changing database date with java

Tags: java, postgresql, jodatime

I have a date that was entered incorrectly in the database (Postgres). e.g.
`0019-07-01 00:00:00`

I just need to change the year to 2019. I'm trying to adjust it with JodaTime. But alone the transformation from java Date to JodaTime and back distorts the date to `Mon Jul 03 00:06:32 CET 19`

I don't understand why.

```
Date falseDate = ...
System.out.println(falseDate); // 0019-07-01 00:00:00.0
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(falseDate);
System.out.println(newDateTime.toString()); //0019-06-28T23:53:28.000+00:53:28
```

Comment: You could easily do that with SQL. But if you want help with your Java code, you need to **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add your code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. ([edit] your question, do not post code in comments)

Comment: "I don't understand why." - I don't understand why as well. Why? Because you didn't share any code so I can't know what you're doing :) - Btw, why are you using JodaTime and not the new java.time api?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to do that with a SQL statement?

Comment: So where does `falseDate` come from? How do you read that from the database? Is that a `java.util.Date` or  a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: its a java.util.Date

Comment: I guess Date is UTC and DateTime is local time zone. What about setting the time zone of newDateTime to DateTimeZone.UTC?